# My Pandas script freezes disk after read/write >3000 csv files

Tags: python, pandas, io

I am working on a script to read a collection of ~11,000 csv files (each < 1M). I used Pandas to modify it and write to new csv files. On my Ubuntu box with slow HDD, the speed is about 5-10 seconds per 100 files. The iostat shows %iowait up to ~50%. But after about 3000 files (each time is different), the %iowait would jump to 80% or higher and the entire system becomes sluggish to finally no response. The iostat continued print output (slowly). The r/s will drop, but %iowait maintained at 80-90%. If I cancel (Ctrl+C) the script right after the io jump, the system will back to normal after a few minutes.

Here is the script. I removed most of the DataFrame process already. The script can finish if I remove even more Pandas manipulation (the dtype setting line).

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

def main():
    src_path = Path("/mnt/4TB/test/tmp/src")
    dest_path = Path("/mnt/4TB/test/tmp/dest")

    files = src_path.glob("**/*.txt")

    for file in files:
        df_new = pd.read_csv(
            file, names=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'],
            dtype={'a': str, 'b': str}, # if this line is removed, the script will manage to finish
            header=0,
         )
            df_new.to_csv(data_path / f"{file.name}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It seems any Pandas data process will lead to high io eventually. I tested the same on Windows subsystem linux, which is on NVMe. The process was much faster, but it still freeze after ~ 5,000 files if all the Pandas functions in place.

Any idea what the reason for it and any suggestion how to handle this? I wonder if asyncio is the answer.

Comment: Have you tried using `memory_map=True`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just gave it a shot and got the similar results, the %iowait went to 80%+ after ~3300 files with the above code.